# Override background-color in <html> tag with Vue-Material

Tags: vue-material

I am using Vue-material with the default theme.

This theme adds a `background-color` on the `<html>` as below -

[image]

Is there an easy way to change this to `white`? I do not want to change anything else in the theme, so I don't know if it makes sense to customise the theme. Though I tried to customise the theme using instructions from [here](https://vuematerial.io/themes/configuration/) but no success. I just couldn't figure out where to include the customisation code snippet as demonstrated in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write the style to have your own background color:

```
html.md-theme-default {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried doing this in my `index.html` file, but Vue overrides this. I think it's because the Vue theme styles are applied after rendering the HTML file.